# Read and write sqlite database synchronisation in PhoneGap (Android and JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sqlite, android-sdk-2.3

I have a sqlite database in my android application which requires frequent updates from Android as well as Javascript.

But While Android makes updates in database if during that time Javascript code tries to update then it gets error.

Same is the case when Javascript updates the database then if Android tries to update it it gets error that database is locked.

So i need to synchronise both the operations , is there any plugin that takes care of it of its own. Any help regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

that is the normal behaviour of sqlite, only one client can write to the database at one time: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Comment: you must handle the error and try later. there is suggestion on how to do it at the end of the answer 5 in the sqlite faq.

Comment: there might b some plugin like PGSqlite plugin for ios that takes care of these things, doing it manually for so many operations is not feasible in my case